# extract style tags line from head with preg_replace and preg_match_all

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, preg-match-all

In php want to collect style lines from the html head and replace them with blank space.
I trying using preg_match_all and preg_replace but i don't have a working solutions.

```
$myhtml="
 <title>my title</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style1.css" />
 <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js" />
 <link href="style2.css" type="text/css"  rel="stylesheet" />
 <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <link href="style3.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
 <![endif]-->
 <meta name="author" content="i'm the author" />
 <!--[if lt IE 6]>
    <link href="style4.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"/>
 <![endif]-->
 <style>
   #body{background-color:#CCC;}
 </style>
";
```

i am looking to the result

```
$myhtml="
 <title>my title</title>
 <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js" />
 <meta name="author" content="i'm the author" />
";

$extracted_styles="
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style1.css" />
 <link href="style2.css" type="text/css"  rel="stylesheet" />
 <!--[if gt IE 8]>
    <link href="style3.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
 <![endif]-->
 <!--[if lt IE 6]>
    <link href="style4.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"/>
 <![endif]-->
 <style>
   #body{background-color:#CCC;}
 </style>
";
```

The php: i try to extract conditional css first, link rel later but already the first step dosen't work

```
$styles='';

//extract conditional css
preg_match_all('/<!--(.*)-->/i', $myhtml, $matches);
$styles.=implode(" ",$matches);
preg_replace('/<!--(.*)-->/i', "", $myhtml);
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem I see is that the beginning of your regex and the ending are in different lines. Change your rule to:

```
$styles='';

//extract conditional css
preg_match_all('/<!--(.*)-->/is', $myhtml, $matches);
$styles.=implode(" ",$matches);
preg_replace('/<!--(.*)-->/is', "", $myhtml);
```

as the s modifier implies that the dot (.) not only grabs "anything but ends of line", but also "ends of line".